# iguanatex error

Tags: powerpoint

So I typed up a powerpoint presentation yesterday and today realised I made an error and went to edit today. Now getting this error: could not start process:

```
"pdflatex" -shell-escape-output-format dvi-interaction=batchmode 
"IguanaTex_tmp.tex"". GetLastError returned 0
```

anyone have any ideas?

This is the code that compiled successfully yesterday:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\pagestyle{empty} 
\begin{document} 
$\triangle \theta = 2\int_{r_{\!1}}^{r_{\!2}}\frac{L}{L^2}\frac{dt}{dr}dr$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, very few people who frequent this site are reliable psychics. (Actually, if we were any good at all at divination, we probably wouldn't be hanging out at this site to begin with...) To improve your chances of getting a usable answer, do tell us please what you did yesterday, when things still seemed to "work", and today, when things are no longer working. Do also tell us which OS, which TeX distribution, and which front-end editing software you employ.

Comment: @Mico so I typed this code yesterday


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

$\triangle \theta = 2\int_{r_{\!1}}^{r_{\!2}}\frac{L}{L^2}\frac{dt}{dr}dr$


\end{document}

Comment: @Mico and all I did was click the edit latex display and change and L^2 to an r^2

Comment: Off-topic: the use of `\triangle` in your code snippet would seem to quite "original", to put it euphemistically. You may want to replace `\triangle` with `\Delta`...

Comment: I've taken the liberty of moving your LaTeX code into the body of the posting.

Comment: Do tell us which TeX distribution and which front-end editing software you employ. Incidentally, why are there three [3] instances of `"` in `"IguanaTex_tmp.tex""`?

Comment: @Mico sorry I am unsure what you mean. I just downloaded iguanatex to Microsoft powerpoint

Comment: What happens if you try to compile a simple document using the command prompt, i.e., save the above code in a file using Notepad, with the extension .tex (for example yourfile.tex), then start a Windows command prompt, navigate to the folder where you saved the file, and type `pdflatex yourfile.tex`? If that works then there is a problem with IguanaTex, otherwise it's a problem with pdflatex.